# Are there any solutions to this problem in spotdl that is used in py file?

Tags: python-3.x, flet

When i use spotdl in a py file for a simple flet application i get an error and i don't know why.I tried to use older versions of spotdl and it worked but i need the newest version of yt_dlp so that is why i can't use an older version of spotdl.

This spotdl version works fine without the flet app but when i include it in an app it doesn't work.

Error:RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Downloader.pool_download' was never awaited self._invoke_excepthook(self)

My code with the flet app where it gived an error:

```
from flet import *
import spotdl


file = open("client_id.txt", "r")
clientid = file.read()
file.close()

file = open("client_secret.txt", "r")
clientsecret = file.read()
file.close()

spotdl = spotdl.Spotdl(client_id=clientid,client_secret=clientsecret)

def main (page:Page):

    def download(e):
        print("start")
        song = spotdl.search([textfield.value])
        spotdl.download(song[0])
        print("done")


    textfield = TextField()
    btn = IconButton(icon=icons.DOWNLOAD,on_click=lambda e: download(e))
    page.add(textfield,btn)

flet.app(main)
```

Here is the whole error that i got :

```
Exception in thread Thread-17 (<lambda>):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3105\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python3105\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\notsporiflyer_final\notspotiflyer\main.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    btn = IconButton(icon=icons.DOWNLOAD,on_click=lambda e: download(e))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\notsporiflyer_final\notspotiflyer\main.py", line 12, in download
    spotdl.download(song[0])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\notsporiflyer_final\notspotiflyer\venv\lib\site-packages\spotdl\__init__.py", line 146, in download
    return self.downloader.download_song(song)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\notsporiflyer_final\notspotiflyer\venv\lib\site-packages\spotdl\download\downloader.py", line 209, in download_song
    results = self.download_multiple_songs([song])
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\notsporiflyer_final\notspotiflyer\venv\lib\site-packages\spotdl\download\downloader.py", line 253, in download_multiple_songs
    results = list(self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks)))
  File "C:\Python3105\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 783, in gather
    fut = _ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
  File "C:\Python3105\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 634, in _ensure_future
    loop = events._get_event_loop(stacklevel=4)
  File "C:\Python3105\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-17 (<lambda>)'.
C:\Python3105\lib\threading.py:1018: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Downloader.pool_download' was never awaited
  self._invoke_excepthook(self)
```